# XML Standard translation with XSLT : dealing with mixed content tag renaming

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I'm "translating" the JATS 1.1 standard to a local standard (Erudit 3.0.0), for local digital publishing purposes. I'm using XSLT 2.0 and working at the instance (artefact) level, so xml documents that were authored by people. I'm dealing with a reduced list of tags from both standards.

The source documents show mixed content in some tags, of course.

My strategy has been to "rewrite" the structural elements of the target standard, dealing with optional tags with conditional statements. I have the skeleton of the target xml document.

I'm not sure how to approach the "translation" of the tag names of the several formatting oriented tags or links and references that are in the mixed content of the lower level structural tags. I've looked around and think the best way to approach this would be to use variables to store the whole xml document at the very beginning of the script, and create a template for each case possible in my list of mixed content tags, then store the result transformation in another variable, and repeat until all options of formatting tags of the mixed content are done, then proceed with the template for the structure tags.

Is this possible? If so, how can I apply a template to a variable?

Thank you.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you posted a [mcve] of what you're trying to accomplish.  From what you've described, I'm failing to see the motivation for multiple passes and variable storage of intermediate results.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Someone has offered me a promissing solution that I'm trying out right now, using the default XSLT processing mode in my favor.

Comment: Don't be afraid to post your code. Whether it's almost right or way off track, you'll get useful feedback here that will help you achieve your goal faster.